# Using sed to remove suffix to dynamic strings

Tags: linux, sed

Im currently face with a problem that i'm trying to use sed so that where if a full stop is present at the end of my string I require to have this removed but its also used elsewhere in the string

e.g

```
abc.def/123.
abc.def/456.
abc.def/789.
```

By using sed to search full stop's it will remove it from abc.def which I don't want.

I want to output the above as-

```
abc.def/123
abc.def/456
abc.def/789
```

The prefix is static and always abc.def

Please could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Updated expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to anchor your `sed` expression to target only the trailing dots:

```
s/\.$//
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working fine.